# Use both variables in an array

Tags: php, arrays

So I have an array as follows:

```
$months = array(
  '01' => 'January',
  '02' => 'Febuary',  
  '03' => 'March',
  '04' => 'April'
);
```

I am putting these into a form select and would like to do the following:

```
<option value="01">January</option>
```

for each variable in the $months array.

Right now I have the following code with the result of: `<option value="">January</option>`

```
<?php foreach ($months as $month): ?>
  <option value=""><?php echo $month; ?></option>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

I'm not really sure how to make use of the first variable in the array. Or if that is even possible. What is teh easiest way to do what I'm trying to do?

Answer (score 3):

You're close. You're just missing the array key which can be used as follows:

```
foreach (array_expression as $key => $value)
    statement
```

So your code might look like:

```
<?php foreach ($months as $month_num => $month): ?>
  <option value="<?php echo $month_num; ?>"><?php echo $month; ?></option>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

See [foreach](http://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php).

Answer (score 2):

your array is `key` & `value` format, so just add key to your loop:

```
<?php foreach ($months as $key => $month): ?>
  <option value="<?php echo $key; ?>"><?php echo $month; ?></option>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

See:: [PHP Arrays](http://www.php.net/manual/de/language.types.array.php)

Answer (score 0):

Try like this :

```
<?php foreach ($months as $key=> $month): ?>
  <option value="<?php echo $key;?>"><?php echo $month; ?></option>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to make your foreach loop as key value pair

```
<?php foreach ($months as $month_key => $month_val): ?>
  <option value="<?php echo $month_key; ?>"><?php echo $month_val; ?></option>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

For more on key value pair refer [Foreach loop with key=>value](http://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
>> What you are not know is how to use key in the array.

<?php

$months = array(
  '01' => 'January',
  '02' => 'Febuary',  
  '03' => 'March',
  '04' => 'April'
);

      foreach ($months as $month_no => $month): ?>
          <option value="<?php echo $month_no; ?>"><?php echo $month; ?></option>
<?php endforeach; 

?>
```

Thanks!